# Audio File in Amazon S3 and Java

Tags: java, audio, amazon-s3

I am trying to join two audio files stored in Amazon S3 using Java. Any ideas how to go about it? Should I use S3ObjectInputStream and then AudioInputStream? I tried that but I am getting unsupported file format error although it is a valid wav file. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I too am trying to do this. So far this is what I got. We use the inputStream to write to a file because as far as I know there is no good way to take the stream and play from MediaPlayer.

Once we have the file we give the path to MediaPlayer and let it play. However my issues are that the audio file does not download completely. I think this has to deal with the buffer size. Also there is no pause or play so you will still need a GUI for that.

Don't forget to use this in a different thread than the main one.

```
            String bucket = getContext().getString(R.string.bucketName);
            String key = "somekey";
            InputStream s3ObjectInputStream = s3.getObject(bucket,key).getObjectContent();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try {

                File targetFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/temp.mp4");
                OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                while( (s3ObjectInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    outStream.write(buffer);
                }


                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "temp.mp4");
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```